# How to set up AWS SNS in one account to be able to receive notifications from SES of other account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I have two AWS accounts:

- Account 1 (111111111111) contains Simple Notification Service Topic (**Email Events Topic**)
- Account 2 (222222222222) contains Simple Email Service with Configuration Set (**Configuration_Set_01**).

I want to add SNSDestination to **Configuration_Set_01** - to be able to publish SES event notifications to **Email Events Topic**

I’ve set up following Topic Policy for **Email Events Topic**:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__console_pub_0",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::2222222222222:root"
      },
      "Action": "SNS:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111111:email-events-topic"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I try to add SNSDestination to **Configuration_Set_01**, referring **Email Events Topic**, it gives me an error ***Could not access SNS topic <…> …***:

[image: Add SNSDestination error]

If **Email Events Topic**'s policy is as follows, destination can be added successfully:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__console_pub_0",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SNS:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111111:email-events-topic"
    }
  ]
}
```

This works:

```
"Principal": {
  "AWS": "*"
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
"Principal": {
  "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:root"
}
```

As I can see here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html - the syntax for **Principal.AWS** value in the second option is correct.

How can I correctly set up Topic Policy on **Email Events Topic** to be able to add it as an event destination only to Account 2's SES Configuration Sets (or any Account 2's services)?

What else should be done to solve the problem in case the problem is not only with the Topic Policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the **Topic Policy**, which works for the described situation:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "MyTopicPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "sid001",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "sns:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111111:email-events-topic",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:222222222222:*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The tricky part was [Condition -> ArnLike](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_ARN):

```
"Condition": {
  "ArnLike": {
    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:222222222222:*"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample link you shared is for S3 resource policy. Could you please try to edit the policy as following which is from [SNS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_Sns.html#AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCase1_Sns)?

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Id":"AWSAccountTopicAccess",
    "Statement" :[
        {
            "Sid":"give-1234-publish",
            "Effect":"Allow",           
            "Principal" :{
                "AWS":"111122223333"
             },
            "Action":["sns:Publish"],
            "Resource":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:444455556666:MyTopic"
        }
    ]
}
```

Additionally, you can also use ["AWS:SourceAccount"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_Sns.html#AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCase4_Sns) condition key with Principal *.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither your code nor "AWS:SourceAccount" doesn't work.

Comment: I've tried the following "AWS:SourceAccount:" condition:
**"Condition": {
  "StringEquals": {
  "AWS:SourceAccount": "222222222222"
  }
}**